# Google map addDomListener not working. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I created div and assigned that element to a variable. Now I want to select by using className but it not working. What wrong I am doing and How can I resolve it? It working if I select it by a variable.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'hoarding_marker';

google.maps.event.addDomListener(div+'.hoarding_marker', 'click', function(){
    console.log('Hello world!');
});
```

Comment: From a quick look at the docs it looks like the first argument to the `google.maps.event.addDomListener` function should be a reference to an element itself. So the first argument should just be `div` I think.

Comment: Also. I think you are reassigning div when adding the class - which you wouldn't want to do.

Comment: And as @martin says, and looking at the Google documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-domListener), that div first needs to be associated with a map.

Comment: it should be a regular DOM event: `div.addEventListener("click", function(){ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

According to Google Maps API documentation, [Listening to DOM Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#DomEvents)

the first argument must be an Object:

> addDomListener(instance:Object, eventName:string, handler:Function)

So in your case it should be:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(
    document.getElementsByClassName("hoarding_marker")[0], 
    'click', 
    function() {
        console.log('Hello world!');
    }
);
```

Or any other variant to find an object (getElementById e.g.)